# What is the max number of BLE CBCentral objects that iOS can simultaneously support?

Tags: ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Putting this another way how many *CBCentral*'s can *CBPeripheralManager* handle.

if iOS complies with the BLE Spec then the answer should be one.

Comment: So it would appear that multiple centrals are supported. Isn't this a deviation from the Spec? or an example of Apples' market enabling pragmatism?

Comment: I have no idea why this is downvoted and voted to be closed. Probably people not reading the spec :-) Gave you a +1 to compensate one of the downvotes.

Comment: Perhaps those who down voted could give us their rational? It would interesting to understand and might assist others in the formation of future postings. Anyway we got to sanity in the end, thanks again for sharing your knowledge and insight of BLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the BLE 4.0 spec only defines behavior for one central per peripheral. There are some newer chips that introduce mesh support, though.

CoreBluetooth deviates from the spec at certain points because the iOS device differs from a typical peripheral. While such a peripheral normally only has one use case, an iOS device has potentially multiple apps running on it serving different purposes. It would be impractical to only support one concurrent physical connection.

Tests have revealed that an iOS device can handle about 8 concurrent physical connections while being a central - those numbers are probably similar for being in peripheral mode.

Note that one of the problems of this spec deviation shows up when multiple apps on a single central iOS device connect to a peripheral. As there is only one physical connection between the two devices, the peripheral has no way to distinguish the different central apps when only using pure BLE knowledge. This leads to sophisticated design requirements especially when doing things like streaming over BLE.